# Using Ganache provided address but still unable to vote

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, ganache

There is a function in my smart contract which I have deployed on local blockchain called

`vote(uint _candidateId)`.

When calling this from **truffle console**

`app.vote(1,{from : web3.eth.getAccounts().then(e=>{ return e[1]})})`

It returns

`Uncaught Error: Returned error: sender account not recognized`

Although

`web3.eth.getAccounts().then(e=>{ return e[1]})`

returns an address that is provided by GANACHE and is known to GANACHE.
I can't solve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the result from the `getAccounts()` call to a variable and then calling `app.vote`, passing that variable to the `from: ` param? You can also check whether that variable has a value, before passing it to `app.vote`

Comment: @Milkncookiez yes I have tried. The variable has the value I intended.